# Oracle APEX - report download Internal Server Error

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have an interactive grid that displays over 250k records and has more than 30 columns. When I attempt to download the report in csv format, I get an `Internal Server Error`. How can I get around that? Is there a way to limit the number of records (I know that when there are fewer records it works fine)? Is there a way to automatically split report in two parts and download two separate files?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add filters to your SQL Query, that way the end user downloads the data they really need.

For example:
1. Create some items like Select List.

2. Enter the proper filter in your SQL Query, as follows:
   [image: SQL Query including items page to filter data]
3. Include the items in *Page Items to Submit*.
4. Create a Dynamic Action to refresh your IG when the end user selects a different value for the items

Comment: The user wants it all

Comment: Is it possible to replicate the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: it appears to be a server setting

Comment: You can check your ORDS logs to determine where the problem is.